# tf.keras input layer only for use during inference

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'd like to create an auxiliary input layer that I use solely during inference time, but can't figure out how to do it. I'd like to do something like the following:

```py
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(784,))

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer((64,), name='input_foo')(x)
predictions = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data, labels)  # starts training
model.save('foo.h5')

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('foo.h5')
inference_model = tf.keras.Model(model.get_layer('input_2'), model.output)
```

However, I get the following error upon loading:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_foo_2:0", shape=(None, 64), dtype=float32) at layer "input_foo". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Comment: What purpose does this serve?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal It's too complicated to explain in a comment. Basically it is impossible for me to have the same input pipeline during inference as during training. I need to input my data after I've performed an STFT during inference, but I need to input a waveform during training. My life would be a lot simpler if there was an auxiliary input. Then I wouldn't have to chop up the layers and reconnect them.

Comment: Check how to concatenate layers in keras, that will be your friend

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new model with input2 and output and load the weights from the trained model. 
or try to write a subclassing model by utilizing the training parameter in the call method as below.

```
def customModel(tf.kears.models.Model):
    def call(inputs, training=True):
        if training == True:
            #do your model for training
        else:
            #do your model for inference
```

Comment: I have several models and am trying to avoid having to maintain multiple versions of each model. The subclassed model suggestion is good. However, support for subclassed models is still inferior in tensorflow. As of 2.2.0 I still can't get distributed training to work with a subclassed model.

Comment: you can do that with custom training loops I think.

Comment: Was hoping to do it with keras though.